# what does chess& = board[i] mean?

Tags: c

```
char chess = _board[0];
    for (char i = 1; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        chess &= _board[i];  //?
    }
```

board is a 1-d char array.
what does chess& = board[i] mean?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The following statement:

```
x &= y
```

... is equivalent to:

```
x = x & y
```

... and, in the above, the ampersand (&) is the "bitwise and".  The result of "x & y" is a value that has a  1 in all the bits where both x and y have corresponding 1 bits, and everywhere else the bits are 0.

Answer (score 4):

`&=` is the compound [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) and assignment operator. What it does is that it takes the bits in `chess` (which is 8 bits as a `char`) and ANDs them with the corresponding bits of `_board[i]`. Then it assigns the results back to `chess`.

In effect, together with the loop this causes each bit of `chess` to be set if all of the values in `_board` has the corresponding bit set.

Further: since `_board` is 8 items times 8 bits, I 'll assume that each item represents a row and the bits of the item represent the columns a-h of that row. The presence of an 1 in a bit position represents *something* (we don't know what).

So the end result would be that `chess` contains an 1 in each of its 8 bits if and only if the *something* exists all rows on the corresponding column a-h of the chessboard.

Comment: No, it causes each bit of `chess` to be set if *every* value in `_board` has that bit set.  `|=` would give the result you describe.

Comment: @caf: My mistake. Late at night over here.

Answer (score 1):

It translates to `chess = chess & _board[i];` where & is the bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 1):

`&=` is a combination AND and assignment.  Therefore `chess &= _board[i]` is equivalent to `chess = chess & _board[i]`

Answer (score 0):

It means take the bitwise `AND` of chess and _board[i] and set chess equal to that value.